# ios image uploading is not working, But file name is submitted and database is updating

Tags: php, ios, swift

The code is given bellow.

the file name is getting submitted to the server. But the image is not uploading

```
func PostImageToServer(Image:UIImage, BaseUrl: String , imageKey:NSString)
        {

            let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: BaseUrl as String)!
            let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)


            let imagename = Image.description
            print(imagename)
            let BoundaryConstant = "********"
            let contentType = NSString .localizedStringWithFormat("multipart/form-data;boundary=\(BoundaryConstant)")
            request.setValue(contentType as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            let body = NSMutableData()

                        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(Image, 0.3)
                        if((imageData) != nil)
                        {
                          body.appendData(String(format: "\r\n--\(BoundaryConstant)\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

                            body.appendData(String(format: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileToUpload\"; filename=\"userpic.jpg\"\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

                            body.appendData(String(format: "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
                            body.appendData(imageData!)
                            body.appendData(String(format: "\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

                    }

                    body.appendData(String(format: "\r\n--(BoundaryConstant)--\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

                    print(body)

            let postLength = NSString(format: "%lu", CUnsignedLong(body.length)) as String
            request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            request.HTTPBody = body

            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

                guard error == nil && data != nil else {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }

                do {
                    self.jsonRes = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments ) as! NSDictionary

                    print("jsonData : \(self.jsonRes)")

                    //   print("jsonDataCount : \(self.jsonData.count)")


                }
                catch let dataError {

                    print(dataError)
                    let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
                                      // return or throw?
                    return
                }

            })


            task.resume()
        }
       }
```

the php code is given bellow:

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . date('m-d-Y_hia') . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$tager_file_name=  basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

Comment: is there more php than that? Where do you think the error is - in the PHP or iOS code?

Comment: try this tutorial http://www.kaleidosblog.com/how-to-upload-images-using-swift-2-send-multipart-post-request

Comment: Error is not with php code ..because Postman response is good and working properly

Comment: It's better to use a networking library like `AFNetworking` for image upload.

Comment: this code not submitting images but getting response from server and if i am passing some other params thats getting submitted successfully..only problem with the image upload.......

Comment: Check this link for the answer   "http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/image-upload-example/". Now it getting uploaded....Thank you all to the response